# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi /2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\arctan(x)}}\right) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've come across the following integral: $$\int_0^{\pi /2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\arctan(x)}}\right) dx$$

I haven't been able to make any of the obvious methods work (or make things easier, for that matter). Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: But tan(0) = 0 and arctan(0) = 0 ... doesn't seem to be well defined

Comment: @EugenCovaci the same is true for $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}$, yet integrating over $(0,c)$ with $0<c<\infty$ still works out fine.

Comment: For the first term it suffices to make the change of variable $t=\sin^2 x$ to obtain a beta function. However for the second I have no idea.

Comment: The tangent part is easy to calculate; you can use the beta function. The arctangent part is... well, I will be surprised if it has either an antiderivative or a closed form.

Comment: Nothing to say more than Sangchul Lee. Maybe just: the integral of the tangent part equals $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: Where did you come across the integral? Please edit the question to include additional background and motivation. Also, please include a description of what you have already tried. These things help make the question more compelling, help others find it, and help others write more useful answers.